# Can't initialize static final field in constructor

Tags: java, final

Why am I not allowed to assign the final modifier in the following case:

```
public static final float aspectRatio;

public TestBaseClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    aspectRatio = screenWidth/screenHeight;

}
```

I thought when I declare a variable as final and leave it blank(not initialized) I need to add a value in the constructor as it is the first to be called and every class has one.

But I get an error from eclipse that says:`The final field TestBaseClass.aspectRatio cannot be assigned`.

Why?

Comment: Is that an instance variable or a class variable?

Comment: Isn't a static variable always a class variable? Because it can only exist one of it? In that case only one `float aspectRatio`?

Comment: Right. And a constructor initializes an _instance_ or a _class_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis an instance? :O

Comment: Right. There are (can be) multiple instances, only one class. A `final` variable can only be initialized once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aspectRatio` is `static`, but you're trying to initialize it in the constructor, where it will be set every time a new *instance* is created. By definition, that's not final. Try using a static initialization block, instead.

```
public static final float aspectRatio;
static {
    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    aspectRatio = screenWidth/screenHeight;
}    
public TestBaseClass() {
    // Any instance-based values can be initialized here.
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and now I understand why! Thank you ;)